# What might be the reason this question was deleted by a moderator?

Tags: discussion, moderators, deleted-questions

[This question](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/627236/rc-circuits-with-input-step-current/627244#627244) has been deleted by a moderator but there is no clear indication why this deletion was made as far as I can see: -

[image]

What might be the reason for this deletion given that there were two answers already made prior to the deletion? Clearly, the question would likely have been deleted in the fullness of time due to it requiring more information but, a single-strike mod intervention does appear to be a little heavy-handed.

Answer (score 4):

Because the user of the original post requested it. I would think it would be stressful if one has to worry everytime a small amount of rep is lost.

Comment: OK, but I think your reasons are wrong. Once answers are given you should not do this in my opinion. For similar reasons we encourage op's not to make changes to their question that invalidate previously given answers.

Comment: I agree, there are reasons for keeping an answer. There are also reasons for deleting it, in this case the OP gave a good reason to delete it, so it was deleted.

Comment: The general stance for post deletion should be that no valuable content should be destroyed. What the OP thinks doesn't matter, at least not everywhere else on SE. As for if that question with the two answers in the linked post count as "valuable", well that's arguable, both answers are kind of just glorified comments. I'm not sure if it makes sense to have them merged into the [duplicate](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/627248/order-of-an-rc-circuit).

Comment: A more relevant concern: is it really wise to delete down-voted questions by a new user instead of encouraging them to fix the question through edits? Because that question will still sit there counting towards this user's automated question ban. Surely the new user can't know of this, but moderators ought to. In this case, fixing the question might have rendered the answers obsolete, but then maybe that's because they should have been posted as comments instead of answers.

Comment: Isn't the usual solution this this kind of issue to disassociate the question from the OP's profile, rather than deleting it entirely? That way the members who spent time on answering the question don't get "punished".

Comment: @brhans That is the usual solution, it depends on the reasons the flagger gives, they gave a good reason. Also, an error made by a user in LT spice on a specific problem is likely to have little value to no one else.

Comment: @Lundin my answer isn't a glorified comment. It was a well-thought out explanation for what the OP likely did incorrectly and, as such has value. In all probability, he saw my answer realized his mistake and asked for the whole thing to be deleted. That act of deletion, in my opinion was an incorrect thing to do.